# Searching within a list of strings with anything in another list of strings in Excel

Tags: excel, lookup

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bO0w.png)

[image: Example with desired result]

I need to find anything in column B within the strings in Column A and output the cell in Column A in Column C.

I know if it is a short list I can do the highlight cell if a text contains x with Conditional Formatting. However, I have a long list of items that I need to check within the strings of another list.

Let me know if anymore detail needs to be provided. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You you want to just know if duplicates exist? Or do you want to keep a list of the duplicates?

Comment: The criteria in column B might come up multiple times within the strings of column A.

Comment: So do you want all of them in different columns or just the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Array formula with wildcards:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$B$1:$B$3&"*",A1)),1,0),0)),"Y","N")
```

It is an array and need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

The search area represented in this small example, `$B$1:$B$3` when enlarged must be to the exact range of lookups or it will not return correct values.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I need to find the items in column B in the cells in column A. Like I want to know if A1 contains anything in column B.

Comment: That is what it did it found the B1 in A3 and returned A3. @charlie

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of confusing. It would be more clear if the cells in column B are in column C, and the output in column B.

I want to see if A1 has anything in column B, then A2, then A3, then A4, and so on.

Comment: It would be more clear if you added your expected result to your screenshot, so people know what to aim for. A picture is worth a thousand words, sometimes. Edit your question and post a screenshot that shows the expected outcome with your data sample.

Comment: @teylyn sorry, I uploaded a picture with the desired result.

Comment: How hard is it to put in words: Show a Y if there is a match, show a N if there is no match?

Comment: Thanks Scott! That works! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-IE/Article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d), type the following in cell C1, then press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,FIND(B:B,A1)<>"#VALUE!",0))
```

Drag it down column C to match number of rows in column A. You can then put a conditional formatting/filter to see what row in A has substring in B.

If you simply want a yes/no result, enter the following into D1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C1:C6,"<>0")>0,"Found","Not Found")
```

Comment: I need to find out if the strings in column A contains any strings in column B.

Comment: So you only want a yes/no result?

Comment: Yes/No result is fine.